# Gets metrics from different measurements in the same row

Tags: grafana

[image]

[image]

There is the query :

```
SELECT 
  last("used_percent") AS "USED MEMORY", 
  last("uptime_format") AS "UPTIME" 
FROM "mem", "system"
```

How can I get those two metrics on the same row ?

Comment: Use Grafana's transformation

Comment: @JanGaraj Yes that's what I was thinking about but I don't know which transformation with which parameters I should use